# Extracting value from a nested array in Spark

Tags: arrays, dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have below output from my query.

| id | info |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"t":{"t_id":"5678","timestamp":1675664495,"tc_id":"12345","properties":[{"k":"psct","value":"IN"},{"k":"ptt","value":"SC"},{"k":"pcd","value":"IN, 2023-02-03"}]}},{"t":{"t_id":"1234","properties":[{"k":"psct","value":"IN"},{"k":"pctt","value":"SC"},{"k":"pcd","value":"IN, 2023-02-04"}],"timestamp":1675749213,"tc_id":"67890"}} |

I want to get the data for `k` and `value` in different columns

My output should be like this:

| id | t_id | k | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5678 | psct | IN |
| 1 | 5678 | ptt | SC |
| 1 | 5678 | pcd | IN, 2023-02-03 |
| 1 | 1234 | psct | IN |
| 1 | 1234 | ptt | SC |
| 1 | 1234 | pcd | IN, 2023-02-04 |

Not able to extract the values.

Can I get some assistance on this please?

These needs to be written in Spark DataFrame.

Comment: Which language you are using Scala, Python ?

Comment: Also your json is broken, try to put it on beautify app/site it will not work

Comment: I am using Scala

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for you help @Abdennacer Lachiheb.

I managed to get my question answered myself. Below is the solution.

```
 val test = spark.sql(s"""select 
                            t_id,
                            info
                    from kh.details""")
                    .withColumn("info_new", explode(col("info")))
                    .withColumn("properties", get_json_object($"info_new", "$.t.properties"))
                    .withColumn("props", from_json($"properties",ArrayType(StringType)))
                    .withColumn("props_info",explode($"props"))
                    .withColumn("key",get_json_object($"props_info", "$.key"))
                    .withColumn("value",get_json_object($"props_info", "$.value"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the info column is of type array but doesn't have "[" and "]" at the beginning and at the end of the column, so the solution is to add them using concat function, and only now you can convert your json using from_json in spark:

```
val df = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
  ("1", "{\"t\":{\"t_id\":\"5678\",\"timestamp\":1675664495,\"tc_id\":\"12345\",\"properties\":[{\"k\":\"psct\",\"value\":\"IN\"},{\"k\":\"ptt\",\"value\":\"SC\"},{\"k\":\"pcd\",\"value\":\"IN, 2023-02-03\"}]}},{\"t\":{\"t_id\":\"1234\",\"properties\":[{\"k\":\"psct\",\"value\":\"IN\"},{\"k\":\"pctt\",\"value\":\"SC\"},{\"k\":\"pcd\",\"value\":\"IN, 2023-02-04\"}],\"timestamp\":1675749213,\"tc_id\":\"67890\"}}"),
)).toDF("id", "info")

val innerSchema = new StructType()
  .add("t_id", StringType, true)
  .add("timestamp", LongType, true)
  .add("tc_id", StringType, true)
  .add("properties", ArrayType(
    new StructType()
      .add("k", StringType, true)
      .add("value", StringType, true)), true
  )

val schema = ArrayType(new StructType()
  .add("t", innerSchema, true))

val resDf = df.withColumn("info", concat(lit("["), col("info"), lit("]")))
  .withColumn("info", from_json(col("info"), schema))
  .withColumn("info", explode(col("info")))
  .select("id", "info.*")
  .select("id", "t.*")
  .withColumn("properties", explode(col("properties")))
  .select("id", "t_id", "properties.*")
resDf.show(false)
```

Result:

```
+---+----+----+--------------+
|id |t_id|k   |value         |
+---+----+----+--------------+
|1  |5678|psct|IN            |
|1  |5678|ptt |SC            |
|1  |5678|pcd |IN, 2023-02-03|
|1  |1234|psct|IN            |
|1  |1234|pctt|SC            |
|1  |1234|pcd |IN, 2023-02-04|
+---+----+----+--------------+
```

Comment: Will check and let you know if this works for me.

Comment: The JSON that I have provided is fine. I cannot fix the JSON as it is coming from Source which I have no control. The solution that you have provided gives me NULL value

Comment: @YousufSultan the json is missing "[" and "]" around it, however there's a workaround check my updated answer.

Comment: I have exploded my outer schema and extract the inner schema using the below statement but that is in a string format, I am not able to convert that into array.  `.withColumn("info_new", explode(col("info")))`  `.withColumn("properties", get_json_object($"info_new", "$.t.properties[*]"))`  The result of this does have the missing "[" and "]"

Comment: This is how my properties column from the above code looks like. I want to convert  this to an array and then explode the data.

`[{"k":"psct","value":"IN"},{"k":"pctt","value":"SC"},{"k":"pcd","value":"IN, 2023-02-04"}]`

Comment: can you execute df.printSchema(), and print the results here, I'm not sure what type is your info column

Comment: `root
 |-- t_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- info: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- info_new: string (nullable = true)
 |-- properties: string (nullable = true)`

Comment: Weird, than the first solution should've worked, what's the result of this : df.withColumn("info", explode(col("info")))
  .select("id", "info.*")
  .select("id", "t.*")
  .withColumn("properties", explode(col("properties")))
  .select("id", "t_id", "properties.*")

Comment: the first solution was giving me NULLs. However I have managed to solve the problem using this  

`.withColumn("props", from_json($"properties",ArrayType(StringType)))
  .withColumn("props_info",explode($"props"))
  .withColumn("key",get_json_object($"props_info", "$.key"))
  .withColumn("value",get_json_object($"props_info", "$.value"))`